# QGIS Cutting .csv Files

Tags: qgis

Trying to import a medium-sized .csv file (ten columns, approximately 500 lines) into QGIS.

I have a database in Microsoft Access, and am exporting files from that as .csv to import into QGIS. I have seen the problems using Excel, and so am doing it via OpenOffice. I have also tried making them into .tsv files via Google Sheets.

When I press 'add delimited text layer', the preview window truncates my file to 20 lines. When I then select the fields for latitude and longitude (I'm using UTM), it imports it truncated to (a different) 15 lines. It also changes the latitude and longitude values to either zero or NULL.

The file looks fine in Notepad. If I make it import it without geometry, it still truncates it in the preview window, but then imports the whole table. However, I then can't put the points on the map!

Does anyone know what is going on, or any way to work around this other than creating a new shapefile and manually placing every single point?

EDIT: The data looks like this:

```
ID,Region,Site,Type,Number,Nickname,Secure Dates,Uncertain Dates,Latitude,Longitude,Notes 
1,Messenia,Koryphasio,Tholos,0,,"LH I, LH IIA",MH,"4,094,405.15","560,361.67",
5,Messenia,Pylos,Tholos,5,Grave Circle/Vagenas,"LH I, LH IIA, LH IIB, LH IIIA1",MH,"4,097,946.59","561,721.62",
6,Messenia,Voidokoilia,Tholos,0,,"LH I, LH IIA, LH IIB, LH IIIB1, LH IIIB2",,"4,091,240.82","558,773.89",
```

And so on all the way down.

Comment: You could try using a Spatialite / SQLite database that would handle the data loading better... then you can work in that database instead of a layer in QGIS.

Comment: Your CSV looks very problematic for me. It would be safer to enclose all texts between double quotas, and numbers should be without quotas and without thousand separators.

Answer (score 1):

CSV that looks like this would probably work better:

```
ID,Region,Site,Type,Number,Nickname,Secure Dates,Uncertain Dates,Latitude,Longitude,Notes 
1,"Messenia","Koryphasio","Tholos",0,,"LH I, LH IIA","MH",4094405.15,560361.67,
```

Comment: testing in qgis 2.18.3, it seems that it's enough to remove just the thousands separator. I guess QGIS supports quoted float fields to support numbers in the "3,14159" style